# jQuery: get the value of an input and add that as a class to the enclosing label?

Tags: jquery, css

This has to be simple: how do I get the value of an input and add that as a class to the same input?  I.e., I want to get the value of `gray` and add `class="gray"`to the enclosing label so I can CSS style the label text that reads "Gray".

This is the markup:

```
<li>
<label>
<input type="radio" id="acf-field" name="acf[field_5af32dbd01019]" value="gray"/>Gray
</label>
</li>

<li>
<label>
<input type="radio" id="acf-field" name="acf[field_5af32dbd01019]" value="green"/>Green
</label>
</li>
<li>
```

Using

```
$("li label").each(function() {
var $link = $(this).find("input").val();
```

gets the value of each value; but how do I `.addClass` to each enclosing label, i.e. `<label class="gray">`

**From the answer below, this adds the class to the parent label: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qnzpahrq/**

```
$("li input").each(function() {
      $(this).parent().addClass($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: here is something to get you started - $('input').addClass("yourclass")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it:

```
$("li input").each(function() {
      $(this).addClass($(this).val());
})
```

```js
$("li input").each(function() {
      $(this).addClass($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
<input type="radio" id="acf-field" name="acf[field_5af32dbd01019]" value="gray"/>Gray
</label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label>
<input type="radio" id="acf-field1" name="acf[field_5af32dbd01019]" value="green"/>Green
</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works and adds the class, but I can't get the CSS to actually change the label text itself.

Comment: i.e., in dev tools, the CSS rule is shown as `input#acf-field_5af32dbd01019-green.green` and is not overwritten by other rules, but the label text isn't green.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch If you want the `label` to be green, then you need to select it, not the input.

Comment: Thanks, select it via jQuery or CSS? Simply using .green in the style sheet doesn't work. The html is `<label><input type="radio" id="acf-field" name="acf[field_5af32dbd01019]" class="green" value="green"/>Green</label>`

Comment: Well that depends on what you're trying to do. In your question when you said, "how do I get the value of an input and add that as a class to the same input?" did you really mean "how do I get the value of an input and add that as a class to it's parent label?" https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qnzpahrq/

Comment: Well, yes, as I thought adding a class to the input would allow me to style the label of the input. So the value should be added to the enclosing label instead of the input?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Yes. See the fiddle in my previous post.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Did the fiddle in my comment not answer your question?